# How do I change slime's default inferior lisp when emacs ignores the .emacs file?

Tags: emacs, configuration, common-lisp, slime, clisp

I am trying to configure emacs24 on my Ubuntu 15.10 laptop. I have both SBCL and CLISP installed (and both will run from the command line just fine). I have Slime installed, and I configured the .emacs file thus:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/clisp")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

With Emacs24 running I hit M-x slime and slime starts up, but it's running SBCL, not CLISP. I don't understand why it's ignoring the inferior-lisp-program line. I know that Emacs24 is reading the .emacs file because if I delete everything in the file slime won't run at all. It just doesn't seem to care how I set setq.

I've double checked my paths and both slime and clisp are where the path descriptions indicate. Very confusing! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is the response given:   inferior-lisp-program is a variable defined in `slime.el'.
Its value is "usr/bin/clisp"

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
*Program name for invoking an inferior Lisp with for Inferior Lisp mode.

Comment: Thank you again @jenesaisquoi, I did also try defining after the require, but it still just loaded SBCL.

Comment: check also whether `slime-lisp-implementations` is perhaps set? although I believe `inferior-lisp-program` should “trump” that … Debian `site-lisp` (used to?) have something that used `/etc/alternatives` to overrule Slime's choice, as well, as I understood it.

Comment: Thank you @BRPocock! As this issue has been vexing me since I tried to set it up; I've un-installed and re-installed numerous times. I reached the point where even SBCL wasn't working. Finally I uninstalled, reinstalled via 'sudo apt-get install ...' and then ran through the installation instruction on this page: https://golems.github.io/motion-grammar-kit/install.html to get SBCL working again (tried other methods - all failed with .emacs errors.) Pasting the result of running quickslime-helper in SBCL in a terminal window into my .emacs file and changing 'sbcl' to 'clisp' worked this time!